# Jquery combo box fill up textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, combobox

I'm trying to use jquery combo box for my form but it ends up giving a huge list with all the words that are possible. Is it possible that you only choose the first word in that list and suggest that for the textbox to fil in? Instead of giving a big list.

This is my code so far.

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
     $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
       source: availableTags
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<select id="tags" class="easyui-combobox" name="dept" style="width:200px;">
    <option value="aa">aitem1</option>
    <option>bitem2</option>
    <option>bitem3</option>
    <option>ditem4</option>
    <option>eitem5</option>
</select>
```

I couldn't get it to working in jsfiddle for some reason here is the working jquery example: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: I dont understand the question... The JQuery example given in your link is written specifically for textbox input not select. Do you want something that you can start typing into and it provides a list?

Comment: yes i want i dont want it to provide the list but choose the first one in the list as a suggestion just like your typing googl and its allready showing google.com in your adres bar.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkhexj0t/) of the example you provided from JQuery UI

You can play around with it in JS Fiddle to understand how it works better.

When using it in your site you will require the CDN links to both the CSS and JS files here are the links

CSS: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css

Javascript: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js

Or if you want to include them yourself in your header then here is the link to it on Google: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery-ui

---

The code is really quite simple

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
 //Here we create an array of tags
 $(function() {
var availableTags = [
"ActionScript",
"AppleScript",
"Asp",
"BASIC",
"C",
"C++",
"Clojure",
"COBOL",
"ColdFusion",
"Erlang",
"Fortran",
"Groovy",
"Haskell",
"Java",
"JavaScript",
"Lisp",
"Perl",
"PHP",
"Python",
"Ruby",
"Scala",
"Scheme"
]; //in the code below we call the autocomplete method from JQuery UI on the element with the "tags" ID,in this case an input element set as textbox
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags //here is where we pass the array we created earlier so that the javascript knows what to populate the search criteria with
});
});
```

If for some reason you still require a select element to be used for this purpose then have a look at Chosen.js [here](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)

This will provide similar functionality with the use of a select element.

Any questions leave me a comment :)